# How to select an Angular 2 Array Object from JSON

Tags: json, angular, mean-stack

I am very new to Angular 2, and I am having trouble with what I feel is a small, but frustrating problem.

I am building a SPA with two main pages, the admin page and the actual app homepage. The admin panel needs to be able to update several text fields on the home page using a form on the admin panel.

The trick for me is that everyday, the info on the homepage will have different content, and the admin panel needs to be able to input info for future dates using the form, which when the date rolls around, will automatically update the homepage info.

My question is, how can I create a JSON document that holds all of the objects containing the info for the homepage, and then display that date's info on the homepage by filtering the JSON from that date?

If there is a better approach or solution, I would be very grateful to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

First, your Angular2 app will completly run on the client side.
So there is no possibility to create a JSON-file. You will need a backend-server.
Your Angular2 app will GET/POST the content from/to the backend.

And better than a JSON-file would be a database (MySql, MsSql, Postgre, MongoDb, ....)

Comment: I tried using this approach, but (forgive my naivety) when I made an API to communicate with, it said I needed CORS because the API wasn't on the same domain. Does this mean I did it wrong?

Comment: The error is (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.)

Comment: You need to enable cors on the express. Take a look here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: @TristanC that was the right way! and yes, that's "normal" .. cross-domain requests are blocked, you have to enable them explicit.

Comment: I got the API to work, but I cannot seem to be able to parse the JSON data or interpolate it into my HTML. If I load the object directly, it says "Object object:, but if I stringify the JSON, it's just one long line. How do I display individual properties of the JSON, like the object name and id?